# Unexpected symbol 'contains' when conditionally inserting variable template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I can't figure this one out.  Any help is appreciated.  This is driving me nuts, not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have tried replacing 'contains' with 'eq' and 'startsWith' but for some reason it keeps telling me its an unexpected symbol.

Exact error:

(Line: 33, Col: 3): Unexpected symbol: 'contains'. Located at position 8 within expression: elseif contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'user')

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: WebAppComponents
      ref: main
      endpoint: RepoAccess
      type: git
      name: Project/WebAppComponents.git

    - repository: test-data
      ref: main
      endpoint: RepoAccess
      type: git
      name: Project/test-data.git


variables:
- template: Variables/default.yml
- ${{ if contains(variables['resources.repositories.WebAppComponents.ref'], 'user') }}:
  - template: Variables/dev.yml
- ${{ elseif contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'user') }}:
  - template: Variables/dev.yml
- ${{ else }}:
  - template: Variables/main.yml
```

Comment: first thing is that the name of the repos is incorret: it should not include the `.git` extension. I tried and it worked for me

Comment: Your indentation on the `- ${{ if }}` statements appears to be incorrect.

Comment: Btw I am using Azure Devops Server so this may not be an issue with Azure Devops Services

Answer (score 0):

I came across the exact same issue.

I am not sure why this is the case, but indenting `elseif` and `else` conditions further in seems to solve the issue.

Try this

```
variables:
- template: Variables/default.yml
- ${{ if contains(variables['resources.repositories.WebAppComponents.ref'], 'user') }}:
  - template: Variables/dev.yml
  - ${{ elseif contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'user') }}:
    - template: Variables/dev.yml
  - ${{ else }}:
    - template: Variables/main.yml
```